# code works in HeidiSQL but not sequelize (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, heidisql

If I execute the following sequence code sequelize

models.Venta.sum(
        'total'
        , { 
        where: {
          fechaExpedicion: {
            [Op.gte]: '2018-03-31 00:00:00',
            [Op.lte]: '2018-03-31 23:59:59'
          }
        },
          attributes: ['elaboradoPor'],
          group: 'elaboradoPor'
         ,
         logging: console.log
        })
        .then(totalIva => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(totalIva))
        })
        .catch(e=> {console.log(e)})

I see only the first result of the survey (with sequelize).
[result sequelize code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi9ue.png)

With
logging: console.log
I get the SQL instruction for MariaDB:

SELECT `elaboradoPor`, sum(`total`) AS `sum` FROM `Venta` AS `Venta` WHERE (`Venta`.`fechaExpedicion` >= '2018-03-31 00:00:00' AND `Venta`.`fechaExpedicion` <= '2018-03-31 23:59:59') GROUP BY `elaboradoPor`;

If I execute, the select in HeidiSQL gives me the correct results.
[Select HeidySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRhM9.png)

Please, what is missing in the sequelize instruction to obtain the best results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the instruction and used findall () and fn to build the sums and integrated additional operations.

```
models.Venta.findAll({
  where: {
    fechaExpedicion: {
      [Op.gte]: '2018-03-31 00:00:00',
      [Op.lte]: '2018-03-31 23:59:59'
    }
  },
  logging: console.log,
  attributes: [
            'elaboradoPor',
            [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('total')), 'totalSuma'],
            [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('totalIva')), 'totalIva'],
            [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('saldo')), 'totalSaldo']
            ],
        group: ['elaboradoPor']
})
.then(resultados => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(resultados))
})
.catch(e => { console.log(e) 
})
```

La respuesta es: [sequelize final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KljMn.png)